# how to pass jquery array from rails controller to postgresql array column

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

In my project i pass javascript array to rails controller using ajax. It's work fine. That javascript array contains upload image names. In my postgresql database i have array column name images.
In rails controller i try like this

```
@usr_vendor_web_slide.images = params[:A]
@usr_vendor_web_slide.save
```

params are pass to controller and it's alredy work.

```
*******["sm12.png", "sm13.png", "sm11.png"]******
```

but in database images name array not pass to the database. In terminal

```
["images", #<struct 
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::OID::Array::Data encoder=#
<PG::TextEncoder::Array:0x5
7c6b10 "string[]"  elements_type=nil needs quotation>, values=[]>]]
```

appreciate your ideas and helps

Comment: how did you create array type column? did you make it by migration or by serialize it in model?

Comment: @Gabbar by migration

Comment: you should not do this like that, reason being via migration array type column not works in mysql db. i m writing the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-  write a migration to add column `images` of `text` type: -

```
add_column :your_table_name, :images, :text
```

2- in model serialize this column as array type

```
Class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :images, Array
end
```

3- Now if you will check at rails colsole

```
YourModel.new

=> #<YourModel:0x00000005bdac68
 id: nil,
  ......
 images: [],
 ....>
```

4- now you can save data into this array type column:-

```
   @usr_vendor_web_slide.images.push(params[:A])
   @usr_vendor_web_slide.save
```

Note: array type column using migration may not work with some database, but by serialize will work perfectly.

Comment: it work fine. but after solved it i have another problem. If you know anything about this column edit function. help me to settle this.                         Again thanks in advance

Comment: @ThilankaUmayangaJayarathna what you mean for edit function? you want to replace the images names of existing image? am i right?

Comment: yes. you're right. if you have any link or something to refer for edit function @Gabbar

Comment: @ThilankaUmayangaJayarathna hmm i believe it would be just array delete existing content and add push new image string in edit function and its nothing but simple array function, and you can do it.